# How to connect to hidden service sites using port 8765?

Tags: tor

I am using 
    `tor start` 
but it is set as port 9050. I can't seem to find the torrc file. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 if that helps.

Comment: Changing this port will not allow you to connect to things on 8765... see the answer below for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must edit the torrc file in /etc/tor/ in Ubuntu. Change the port from 9050 to 8765. Thanks.

Comment: how do I get to /etc/tor? Is that under C://?

Comment: type the following: `cd /etc/tor` then `nano torrc` scroll to the line that has the port setting of 9050 and change to 8765. please accept answer as correct if this works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's using that port as a socks proxy.  You simply need to either "socksify" the tool that you want to use (see [Proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/howto.html) or configure your browser, for instance, to use 127.0.0.1:9050 as a local Socks proxy.